# Datetime object error while inserting datetime in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, datetime, pyspark

I am getting a error while inserting a datetime object into the pyspark data structure

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType, DoubleType, TimestampType, ArrayType, BinaryType
filename = 'Rekorder_2022-08-24_14-12-42.mf4'
match = re.search(r'(\d+-\d+-\d+_\d+-\d+-\d+)',filename)
date_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(match.group(1),"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
```

Now, I am trying to insert the date into the following pyspark data structure

```
    sdf = spark.createDataFrame(date_time, schema = recorder_files)



    recorder_files = StructType(   [
        StructField('date_time', TimestampType(), False)                   
])
```

> **Error Message**
>
> TypeError: StructType can not accept object datetime.datetime(2022, 8,
> 24, 13, 47, 47) in type <class 'datetime.datetime'>

**What I tried?**

1. I checked that the time variable is of type datetime

type(date_time)
Out[85]: datetime.datetime

2. I could see that the output variable is also of datetime

print(recorder_files)
StructType([StructField('date_time', TimestampType(), False)])

3. I also read that as per the [link](https://www.legendu.net/en/blog/pyspark-func-date/) suggested that we need to add "lit" function of pyspark
   I tried this as well but it didnt work

date_time = lit(datetime.datetime.strptime(match.group(1),"%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S"))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to add this `date_time` with the existing DataFrame use `withColumn()`

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import lit

df.withColumn("date_time", lit(date_time)).show()
```

Note: `lit()` create a column of literal value.

Comment: Hi @arudsekaberne, thank you for the response. Actually the schema I have given here is just a sample of the big strucutre. In case of many fields, then we need to add all those to the "data" is it before giving it to the sdf?

Comment: Do you want to add this `date_time` with a Spark DataFrame as a new column right?

Comment: yes, to say in otherwords, date_time is one of the columns among many other columns